# sum element of a list under certain conditions

Tags: prolog

Consider this situation:

```
       height(a,10).
       height(b,20).
       on(a,d).
       on(b,d).
```

I'm trying to write a predicate that return true if the sum of the height of the elements on **d** is less than 10.

With:

```
   ?- findall(X,on(X,d),Result).
```

I get: Result = [a, b]

but after this point I don't know how to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to sum all the heights so

```
?- findall(H,((on(X,d),height(X,H)), Heights).
```

is satisfied with `Heights` is being instantiated to `[10, 20]`. Now, you need to sum all elements in that list. In SWI-Prolog, there's a builtin predicate that does that (`sum_list/2`):

```
?- findall(H, (on(X,d), height(X, H)), Heights), sum_list(Heights, S).
S = 30.
```

Comment: There was an extra parenthesis, sorry